# Visual Studio Device: Unsupported Instruction Set error while connecting to .Net CF CLR Profiler

Tags: compact-framework, remote-debugging, windows-embedded-compact

I can't connect to my device using `.Net CF CLR profiler`.

I receive the error `Visual Studio Device: Unsupported Instruction Set`.

I'm using an ARM `V7` processor running `WEC7` with a `USB ActiveSync` connection.

Any ideas why I might be getting this error ?

Comment: You need to show some code. We can't magically guess where you are screwing up.

Comment: @jp2code There is no code required to guess anything magically.

Comment: lol. OK, but how does one connect to a `.Net CF CLR profiler`. What namespace and calls are you using?

Comment: @jp2code Well for your clarity, I am not using any code, Net CF CLR Profiler is a tool which I am using for my app's profiling but I am not able to connect, it connects with Windows Mobile Compact 6 version.

Comment: @Alan Yes, I am using CF 3.5

Comment: Apparently NETCF Remote Performance Monitor does not properly support Active Sync on  Windows Embedded Compact 7. It may be the same for CLR profiler. This may help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0fd6095d-3532-460a-9a2e-5beb1d823781/unsupported-instruction-set-message-to-connect-to-netcf-35-device-for-using-remote-performance?forum=winembmngdapp